# How to make a column into a list in R

Tags: r

I'm looking to edit a column in my dataset so that I can make a collection of features one row instead of many. I've considered pivot_wider and dcast but they aren't quite what I'm looking to do.

I start with something like this reprex:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,5),
                 b = c("sunshine","lollipops","rainbows","clouds","rain","dinner","headphones","pen","pencil","desk"))
```

Something like this is my goal.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(2,3,4,5),
                 b = c("sunshine, lollipops, rainbows","clouds, rain","dinner","headphones, pen, pencil, desk"))
```

I appreciate any suggestions that you may have.

Comment: `aggregate(b~a, df, toString)`

Comment: Not quite - I received this error:
Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame

Comment: Did you try it on the example that you have provided in your post?

Comment: I made a typo when copying the text. Thank you, that works!